# Parameterized property in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For example, I have two models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
   # Some fields
   ...

   @property
   def title(self):
      return PageTranslation.objects.get(page=self, language=language).title # I can not pass property to the parameter

class PageTranslation(models.Model):
   page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
   title = models.CharField()
```

And some DRF view, which get_queryset method looks like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
   return Page.objects.all()
```

And serializer:

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Page
       fields = (..., 'title',) # title = property
```

I want to return QuerySet with Page model instances, and use `title` property in serializer, but I can not pass language (that is set somewhere in the request — headers, query param, etc) there.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language
from django.config import settings



class Page(models.Model):

    @property
    def title(self):
        language = get_language() or settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
        return PageTranslation.objects.get(page=self, language=language).title
```

`get_language()` gives you the current active language, if i18n is disabled it gives you `None`, and for that we have the `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` fallback.

For the serializer part, I think you are supposed to explicitly say that your property is a field, ModelSerializer only finds the actual database fields for you, nothing else.

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = (..., 'title',)
```

Answer (score -1):

Register [`django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.5/django/middleware/locale.py) [in your project settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference). This makes `LANGUAGE_CODE` property available in the `request`

In DRF view where there is the `request` context, filter QuerySet by the language.

```
def get_queryset(self):
   return Page.objects.filter(language=self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

Then computed `title` property declared in the `Page` model is not necessary and inefficient.

This is why:

N queries are executed per record in the original QuerySet to serialise a value for the title field. There is great likelihood for an N+1 problem to occur when another model has a many-to-many relation with `Page`.

Also, serialised results can be inconsistent because `title` value can be `null` in cases where the record doesn't exist for the language.